# Homography between known and unknown rectangle corners

Tags: matrices, optimization

I would like to know if there is a solution for the problem of **homography estimation** in the special case in which one of the views is unknown but has some constraints, particularly if we know the points are the corners of a rectangle. In other words:

Given a set of known rectangle corners, can we found the homography between them and a set of reference rectangle corners? 
[image]

**If we set the reference rectangle width to an arbitrary value (let's say, `w=10`), can we solve for both the homography matrix elements and the rectangle aspect ratio? Is it an underdetermined problem?**

Something tells me that with such constraints there should be a solution to this problem, but (beyond basic stuff) my knowledge on optimization tends to zero. My assumption is that this case can be solved by a modification of the basic homography estimation problem, e.g, $X_2 = HX_1$ with the DLT algorithm or something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "This article is about how the mapping of any point can be found, given the projections of the four corners." thank you, but I think that is not what I am looking for. I want to calculate the projection itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: No need to be rude. In your article, you say, and I quote, "To determine the 8 unknown coefficients, we use the coordinates of the projections of the four corners, let , corresponding to **(u,v) = (0,0) , (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)** , in clockwise order and replace them in the general expression..", therefore you assume a reference **square** or, in other words, you already assume an aspect ratio of 1. My question is about "simultaneously solving for both the homography matrix elements and the rectangle aspect ratio", not about computing the coefficients in a trivial case.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398632/